# Prove the statement $\binom{n}{3k+1}=\sum_{i=k+1}^{n-2k}{\binom{i-1}{k}}{\binom{n-i}{2k}}$using combinatorial arguments:

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Prove the following statement using combinatorial arguments:
>
> For all $n,k\in\mathbb{N} $ such that $3k+1\le n$:
> $\binom{n}{3k+1}=\sum_{i=k+1}^{n-2k}{\binom{i-1}{k}}{\binom{n-i}{2k}}$

Hey everyone. I've been thinking about this for a while and I'm lost. I don't even know how to begin. Would be happy to get some help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you mean $\binom{n}{3k + 1} = \sum_{i = k + 1}^{n - 2k} \binom{i - 1}{k}\binom{n \color{red}{- i} + 1}{2k}$?

Comment: @N.FTaussig Thank you! I did, it was supposed to be (n-i). Edited the post

Comment: Would appreciate if I got an explanation for the downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but you present the problem with such spare detail that Readers may be unsure if the notion of "combinatorial argument" is what is causing difficulty.  Sometimes checking small examples, e.g. $n=10$ with $k=0,1,2,3$, can shed light on what makes the formula tick.

Comment: @hardmath I understand. Thanks for the feedback and the advice. The idea of combinatorical argument is indeed what baffled me :)

Comment: It's a curious turn of phrase, but [combinatorial argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof) is sometimes explained as counting the same set of things in two different ways (we should get the same answer, but as here, the expressions may not be obviously equal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  The left-hand side counts the number of ways $3k + 1$ elements can be selected from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.  The right-hand side counts the number of selections in which the $(k + 1)$st smallest element is $i$.  To see this, count how many ways you can select $k$ elements that are smaller than $i$ and $2k$ elements that are larger than $i$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely understand now :)